# qsort() can't understand the detail in C

Tags: c

Why when we use `qsort(), int(*compar)(const void*,const void*)` haven't add any paraments in, but can also do their functions?

Such as this :

```
double vals[NUM];
qsort(vals,NUM,sizeof(double),mycomp);
```

Comment: Are you asking how the compare function is called?  It's called internally in the `qsort` function.

Comment: this question doesn't make sense.  please expand on what you are confused about

Comment: of course not, the question I want to ask is how the mycomp work? When I use qsort,I haven't add parament in mycomp,how can it work as usual?

Comment: when you say "parament" do you mean "parameter"?

Comment: Sorry I typed it wrong .it's parameter .

Answer (score 1):

When you append parenthesis to the identifier representing a function, with a list of parameters between, you're calling the function.

In this case, you don't want to call the function, however. You want `qsort` to call the function to determine whether or not one element is larger or smaller than the other.

Comment: Mmmmmm,does this mean when I use qsort ,I don't have to concern about how mycomp work?

Comment: It means you should write `mycomp` to compare the two items that are pointed to by the two arguments.

Comment: `int mycomp(const void *x, const void *y) { const double *a = x, *b = y; /* return -1 when a is less than b, 0 when they're equal or 1 when a is greater than b */ }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are asking about [function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501) in general.

Here is a simple example of function pointer:

```
int compare(int i, int j)
{
    return i > j ? i : j;
}

void process(int i, int j, int(*pfunc)(int, int))
{
    printf("%d\n", pfunc(i, j));
}

int main(void)
{
    process(1, 2, compare);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example `process` is sort of like `qsort`, while `compare` is the function which we define ourselves. We need to tell `qsort` how to compare data, but we can't access `qsort` directly, so pass our own function to it which tells `qsort` how to compare.

Comment: I agree most of  what you said,but one point I can't understand is that when we use    qsort,we define    mycomp,but we even don't know how the    mycomp proceed data segmentation？

Answer (score 0):

`qsort` is generic.  It doesn't know what type of data it is processing, so it can't simply compare elements using `<`.  What it does instead is let you, the programmer, give it a function to use to compare elements.  So, **yes** you do care about how `mycomp` works, you need to define it.

```
int mycomp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const double *lhs = a;
    const double *rhs = b;
    if (*lhs < *rhs) return -1;
    if (*lhs > *rhs) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

inside of `qsort`, every time it needs to compare two elements it will pass them to your `mycomp` function and examine the result.  If you define it wrong, your array will be incorrectly arranged (unsorted).